# Is it possible to make sure a hook will run last in or after onResponse in Fastify?

Tags: fastify

We are today sending information to topics, apis and some other things that are not needed in the response, as onResponse hooks.

These hooks are added as route level hooks because it is a different setup of hooks for most of our endpoints.

There is also an object that collect information from all hooks and we want to post the information from this object as a last thing before ending the request session.
And this is where the issue is. How can we get this hook to run as a very last hook?

This sendInfo hook is registered with app.register(sendInfo) as the last row before return app.
We want to avoid to add it on every endpoint as a route level hook.